# How do i get to SForceService using .Net Core 3.1 framework

Tags: wsdl, salesforce, .net-core-3.1, web-reference

I am able to connect salesforce by using standard dotnet framework with web reference option. But, i am unable to connect SForceService by using dotnet core  3.1 framework as it is using system.web.services namespace which is not available in .net core 3.1, i have added parter wsdl file using Connected service option, the methods are not exposed to access.

[image]

Comment: I came here looking for an answer, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: same for me, did you get any direction on this  ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work and figure I should help out the community a bit here.

I was able to use the Metadata & Partner WSDL after generating a reference.cs file via WCF tools, you can achieve it either by using VisualStudio (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) or dotnet-svcutil (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x) CLI.

If you're using CLI like me, make sure you have the folder structure created correctly and add reference to the .csproj file.
Folder Structure should look like this:

```
Connected Services 
 Metadata Service
   ConnectedServcie.json 
   reference.cs
Partner Service
  ConnectedServcie.json 
  reference.cs
```

In the csproj:
Add a new ItemGroup property under Project property:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Hope this help =)

Comment: its not compatible with .net core